# Decreasing price of in-app (iOS) auto renewal subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

If I decrease the price of an in-app (iOS) auto renewal subscription would the existing subscriber continue to use service at discounted rate? Or would their auto renewal subscription get cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Apple docs : [Link Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html)

> When their subscription renewal date approaches, customers are notified if the price of an auto-renewable subscription has increased. After their subscriptions expire, they are opted-out of the subscription and must manually renew their subscription at the increased price.
>
> **If the price of an auto-renewable subscription decreases during the subscription period, customers are not notified and the subscription automatically renews at the lower price.**

So it seems that if price goes down, the subscription is renewed at the reduced price, without notification.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's docs ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6 ) cover the case of a price **increase**. Since it does not explicitly cover the price *decrease* case, I would assume that the users will continue at the new, lower rate.

From "Expiration and Renewal" on that link:

> Note: Increasing the price of a subscription doesn’t disable automatic renewal for all customers, only for those customers whose subscription expires in the next ten days. If this change is a mistake, changing it back to the original price means no additional users are affected. If this change is intentional, keeping the new higher price causes automatic renewal to be disabled for the rest of your users in turn as they enter the ten-day renewal window.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't assume auto renewal would happen in case of price decrease. I have to be sure of this before implementation. I am working on an app that has thousands of auto renewal customers and losing their subscription will have immediate impact on business.

Comment: No worries. Seems you have two choices, then: test it in the sandbox or contact Apple DTS to get more definitive of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very) late response to the question but if anyone is looking for the **updated** docs and/or how to **Manage pricing for auto-renewable subscriptions**, [here is the link for it](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc9870599e).

**Decreasing** price is simple, auto renewal takes places as it would normally do.

**Increasing** however is a tad complicated than the prior, I'll just quote from the above link:

> If you choose to increase the price of your auto-renewable
> subscription, you have the option to preserve prices for existing
> subscribers.
>
> If you increase the price of a subscription without preserving prices,
> all existing subscribers must consent to the new price before their
> next renewal date. If they do not consent to the new price or take no
> action, their subscription expires at the end of their current billing
> cycle.
>
> After your price increase goes into effect, Apple will automatically
> inform existing subscribers through email and push notifications, and
> attempt to obtain consent to the higher price. The timing of these
> notifications depends on the length of the subscription, and there is
> a minimum required notice. If a price increase occurs within the
> minimum required notice period, subscribers will renew at their
> existing price for one more billing period, and will be notified
> before the end of their next billing period.